# BufferedImage.getRGB does not return array

Tags: java, bufferedimage

I'm using the method `BufferedImage.getRGB(...)` to get an array of `int`'s from a `BufferedImage`, but when I try to access those `int`'s in the array, I get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` Exception. The `int` array I want to store those values in, seems to have length `0`, even if it looks like the image is correctly loaded. Where am I doing wrong?

Here's the code:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class SpriteSheet {

public String path;
public int width, height;
public int[] pixels;

public SpriteSheet(String path){
    BufferedImage image = null;     
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(SpriteSheet.class.getResourceAsStream(path));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (image == null){
        return;
    }


    this.path = path;
    this.width = image.getWidth();
    this.width = image.getHeight();

    pixels = image.getRGB(0, 0, width, height, pixels, 0, width);

    for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++){
        pixels[i] = (pixels[i] & 0xff)/64;          // remove alpha channel
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        System.out.println(pixels[i]);
    }
}

}
```

The `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` is thrown in the last for cycle, when I try to display the value of the int's.

Comment: Is 8 as the fixed upper limit of the last loop right? Even in that case, it should be ArrayIndexOutOfBounds. Which line exactly throws the NPE?

Comment: Try debug it and check values of getWidth() and getHeight(), or print them.

Comment: Pardon, I made horrible mistake. It actually thorws an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception.

Comment: Lol ..you used width 2 times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
this.width = image.getWidth();
this.width = image.getHeight();
```

To

```
this.width = image.getWidth();
this.height = image.getHeight(); // set height properly
```

---

Change

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
```

To

```
for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
```

Comment: I can't believe I did not see that, I have read that at least 3 times... Thank you so much! Even if I have to admit I feel really dumb right now.

Comment: I got `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` that give me the hint. I never received `NPE`